# ExtJs Json store

Tags: extjs

Is there any way to send JSON store of ExtJs gridpanel to Controller as two dimentional array.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To get an array of records from your store, you could use:

```
var store = gridpanel.getStore();
var records = store.getRange();
// If you don't want any of that metadata referring to the gridpanel.
var rawRecords = records.map(function(r) {return r.data;});
```

To pass that to a controller, the best practice would be to fire an event from the gridpanel and have the controller listen for it.

```
// Somewhere in gridpanel or a reference to whatever your custom class is
gridpanel.fireEvent('rawRecordsEvent', rawRecords);
...
// In controller
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.GridController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            // gridpanel or alias of whatever your custom class is.
            'gridpanel': {
                 rawRecordsEvent: this.onRawRecordsEvent
             }
        });
    },

    onRawRecordsEvent: function(rawRecords) {
        console.log(rawRecords);
    }
});
```

Here is a nice example of how to use a controller to listen to a view component:
http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.app.Controller.html

Comment: This approach is one that my team use a lot. Listening for the event in the controller is great because it keeps you from needing to pass parameters arround. Also, remember to use an event on the grid panel so that you will have a reference of the gridpanel passed in. That way you easily avoid using Ext.getCmp () which can be a performance killer for large pages/doms.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use baseParams option to send any parameters you need.
E.g.:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    baseParams: {some_array: [['1'],['2']]},
    ...
```